# undefined method `batch_change_message_visibility' with AWS-SDK for Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to write a ruby script to change a message error but I'm getting the error batch_change_message_visibility is not a defined method.
Here is the code :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

sqs = AWS::SQS.new(
    :access_key_id => access_key,
    :secret_access_key => access_secret)

queue = sqs.queues.named(queue_name)

messages = []
messages << { :message => message_handle, :visibility_timeout => 5 }
queue.batch_change_message_visibility(messages)
```

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called `batch_change_visibility` - the documentation has the wrong method name.